# Select the videos from UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have UICollectionView and I add all the videos from my photo Library in an array and display them in the CollectionViewCells.

I want to be able select the videos from this UICollectionView.

How do I achieve this ? .Thanks

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview

Answer (score 0):

it's simple. you should use "didSelectItemAt indexPath" method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    // and now you access your view that is in the cell

}
```